# Postgresql: Can't access to file « $libdir/postgis-2.1 » no such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgis

I guess this is a known issue but since I have used a script that removed my postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1, I'm now unable to get rid of this SQL error under Debian.

> Can't access to file « $libdir/postgis-2.1 » no such file or directory

I've done the following:

```
- Remove new unwanted postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2 package installed
- Reinstalling postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1, postgresql-9.4-postgis-scripts and postgis
- Using SQL: ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO '2.1.4' --under postgres user
- Using SQL: ALTER EXTENSION postgis_topology UPDATE TO '2.1.4' --under postgres user
```

And `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;` returns

```
[...]
postgis 2.1.4   2.1.4   PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions.
```

But still this message when accessing object like tables that uses geometry type.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally "solve" the issue compiling **from source** postgis 2.2.2 (that also requires gdal, proj4 and geos) and then issuing

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

since `DROP EXTENSION postgis;` tells me postgis wasn't present anymore.

And finally:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO '2.2.2';
ALTER EXTENSION postgis_topology UPDATE TO '2.2.2';
```

Got access again to my geom data and functions from PostgreSQL 9.4. It seems that compiling from source updated correctly the variable path for postgresql and installed /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/postgis-2.2.so that wasn't present anymore (for postgis-2.1.so as well), even with (re)installing from apt-get.

Hope this will help.

Comment: ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO '2.2.2'; did not work for me, bu ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE; did

Answer (score 5):

First run (as postgres administrator) in the database that needs it (`\c your-database-name`):

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

If this returns successfully, then check what version you have

```
SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();
```

If however, the server returns that it cannot find the extension postgis, then run

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

and again check by running

```
SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu

Enter in postgres interactive shell by using below command

```
sudo -u postgres psql


\c database_name;


ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.4.4";


SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();
```