# Can't create postgis extension in postgresql 11 (Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon)

Tags: postgis, postgresql-11, postgis-installation

I try to run postgis extension on Postgresql 11, using pgAdmin 4 but when trying to create extension I get the following Error:

```
Could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory
```

I installed postgis via

```
sudo apt-get postgis*
```

But `postgis-scripts` including `postgis.control` were missing, I couldn't event find the postgis extension.

Therefore I installed

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-11-postgis-3-scripts
```

and now it shows the files in `/usr/share/postgresql/11/` and I can choose the postgis extension in the pgAdmin Browser when chosing `Extensions > Create  > Extension` but, when try saving it says

```
Could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory
```

I followed the: [stackoverflow issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444577/postgresql-cant-access-to-file-libdir-postgis-2-1-no-such-file-or-directo) but I could not `ALTER EXTENSION`
 and `UPDATE TO 3.0.0`

It tells me `extension postgis doesn't exists`.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting postgresql:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```